# Module projective

Tags: projective-module, maximal-and-prime-ideals, finitely-generated, free-modules

Is this relation true?

- $M$ is projective module if and only if $M_m$ is projective module for every maximal ideal $m$.
- $M$ is finitely generated free module if and only if $M_m$ is finitely generated free module for every maximal $w$-ideal $m$.

Thank you so much

Comment: What is $M$? What is $M_m$? What is $w$?

Comment: I'am so sorry.                                                                                            
 $M$ and $M_m$ are module  and $w$ is operation as star operation.

Answer (score 1):

Over a commutative Noetherian ring a finitely generated module is projective if and only if it's localization at every maximal ideal is projective (in fact free).  Over a non-Noetherian commutative ring it can happen that a finitely generated module is not projective yet every localization is free.  So in general the answer to both of your questions is no.